# how to keep covariates when creating a sequence object from a SPELL data

Tags: traminer

I have a SPELL data in which there are many covariates together with the basic variables (i.e., "id", "begin", "end", and "status"). When I define the SPELL data as a sequence object by "seqdef", it seems that those covariates disappear in the sequence object. Due to this, I cannot make graphs to be grouped by their levels. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This issue has already been addressed. See answer under [http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37526/problems-with-groups-in-traminer][1]


  [1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37526/problems-with-groups-in-traminer